# foreach loop to check radio button

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
            <div class="form-group">
                <label><strong>{{ $question->activityQuestion_text }}</strong></label>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="icheck-inline">
                        {{ Form::radio($question->id, 1, false, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}Yes
                        {{ Form::radio($question->id, 2, false, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}Partial
                        {{ Form::radio($question->id, 0, false, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}No
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

This code block gives me following output

[image]

I want to get these radio button checked from as database value. From data base 
I get checked values for these 5 question as

```
@foreach($activity->questions as $flag) {
    $flag->pivot->activityAnswer
}
```

How can I use that value in the radio button loop to check like following

```
{{ Form::radio($question->id, 1, $flag->pivot->activityAnswer_flag==1, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}Yes
{{ Form::radio($question->id, 2, $flag->pivot->activityAnswer_flag==2, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}Partial
{{ Form::radio($question->id, 0, $flag->pivot->activityAnswer_flag==0, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}No
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do here, but I'll take a crack at it.  It seems like the easiest way to do what you want here is to use a `for` loop rather than `foreach`.  For example:

```
@for($i=0; $i < count($questions); $i++)
     <label>{{ $questions[$i]->activityQuestion_text }}</label>
    {{ Form::radio($questions[$i]->id, 0, $flags[$i]->activityFlag==0, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}Yes
    {{ Form::radio($questions[$i]->id, 1, $flags[$i]->activityFlag==0, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}Partial
    {{ Form::radio($questions[$i]->id, 2, $flags[$i]->activityFlag==0, ['class' => 'icheck']) }}No
@endfor
```

Hopefully I've understood your question right.  Cheers!